# Why does FBX exporter use v6.1.0?

Tags: animation, export

I'm trying to export a mesh with bone animation to the FBX format, for consumption by Assimp. Although the Assimp website says otherwise, the source code does support FBX files, but only versions 7.1.0 through 7.3.0. When I export to FBX from Blender, the version number is 6.1.0.

Is there a specific reason why the exporter uses 6.1.0 and not a newer version? It seems like the FBX exporter is the most heavily used (and hopefully most heavily developed) exporter in Blender?

Also, is there a major difference between 6.1.0 and 7.1.0? Can I just manually edit the exported file so that Assimp thinks it's getting a v7.1.0 file?

Comment: It uses 6.1.0 because no one has implemented 7.1.0. If you need it really badly you could add it your self, or hire a developer to add it.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a 7.1.0 spec sheet? I do need it kind of badly.

Comment: Why not have assimp import the blend file?

Comment: Assimp loads Blender geometry but currently does not handle animation. I should have mentioned that I'm doing bone animation.